# "No such file or directory" after executing a link

Tags: hard-link

I downloaded Tor Browser and I want to add a shortcut to it to the desktop.

So I wrote:

`ln /home/myusername/Documents/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop /home/myusername/Desktop/start-tor-browser.desktop`

But when I do `/home/myusername/Desktop/start-tor-browser.desktop` I get this error:

`/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: No such file or directory`

The reason is that the `.desktop` file has a relative path:

`X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach`

How do I make a shortcut to Tor Browser on the Desktop without modifying Tor Browser's files? (so I don't want to change the relative path to an absolute one)

Answer (score 4):

Just copy the `.desktop` file and adjust it. The desktop file is unlikely to change with updates anyway.

Your approach with hard or symbolic links does not work, as the `.desktop` file is evaluated respective to its "perceived" location, not the real location.

Comment: As a convenient side note (after you corrected the desktop file,you can register tor as an desktop app. So you can use your app launcher: `./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app`